# SpeechRecognizer onResults not firing

Tags: java, android, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

I have a fairly strange problem. I have a android app for which I'm adding speech recognition using the `SpeechRecognizer` class. I've created class implementing RecognitionListener, which  just prints a log message for each event. And everything seems fine. onReadyForSpeech gets fired, onBeginningOfSpeech gets fired and onEndOfSpeech gets fired.

One important event doesn't get fired though, onResults :p

So in summery, everything seems fine, no exceptions are thrown, and I get events telling me that it successfully have started and stopped listening. Am I missing some extra for the intent which tells the SpeechRecognizer that it needs to send results to onResults or something like that?

I set up the intent as follows

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
```

the SpeechRecognizer is done as

```
    SpeechRecognizer speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
```

And I start listening with

```
speech.startListening(intent);
```

Comment: Check out the error code you receive from `onError`.

Comment: onError wasn't called, that was the odd part. I isolated it to a network issue, since it works if i turn off wireless and use 3G. If i turn off 3G as well (no network at all) onError fires. Tried another wireless and it works on there as well, but at my work wireless, it doesn't work and does not call onError.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the problem as stated in the problem statement. I have two Voice Recognition Services available (Google and one more). I was going wrong inside an inner class:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable stopListeningRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    speechRecognizer.stopListening(); 
                }
            };
```

Instead of writing this in the method which was using it, I had put it at the beginning of an inner class.

This was stopping the call to `onResults`. As soon as I inlined this in the method which actually used it, `onResults` worked  fine.

Hope this helps you..  :)

Answer (score -1):

Whether `onResults` is called or not depends on the app that provides the speech recognition service. Your problem description is incomplete because you do not mention which app you are using for speech recognition. Is it Google Voice Search? In any case your question is rather a bug report and instead of Stackoverflow, it should be directed to the producer of the app along with the details about the app version, your Android version, hardware, etc.

Note that there is also a 2-argument version of `createSpeechRecognizer` which you could use to make sure that you get the speech recognizer that you want.

Also, have a look at the app Babble which uses the same `SpeechRecognizer`-interface and comes with source code:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.lukin.android.babble
- https://github.com/lukin0110/babble/blob/master/android/app/src/be/lukin/android/babble/BabbleActivity.java

(Sorry to advertise my own app, but maybe it's helpful in this case, i.e. you could check if it works as expected or does it have the same issue.)